# After FB.logout(), reload the page state still returns "connected"

Tags: angular, facebook

My test environment is angular 6 on `https:\\localhost:4200`.

I using [ngx-facebook](https://github.com/zyra/ngx-facebook) to do facebook login, logout.

When I loading my web pages the `this.fb.getLoginStatus()` return login default state is `connected` (Should the state be `not_authorized`?).

```
this.fb.getLoginStatus().then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        }).catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
```

[image]

When I used the logout function `this.fb.logout()` the `this.fb.logout()` is return state `unknown`,should this mean that I have successfully logged out?

```
this.fb.logout().then(response =>{ 
   console.log(response);
});
```

[image]

After reloading the page, the `this.fb.getLoginStatus()` return status is still `connected`.

[image]

What steps do I lack to achieve full logout?